# How to send a request to localhost using 'net/http' fails with end of file reached (EOFError)

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm using Ruby version 2.3.0.

I want to check when my application is up, and I wrote this method for my "deployer".
At runtime `http.request_get(uri)` raises

```
EOFError: end of file reached
```

when I pass `http://localhost` as a first argument into the method:

```
require 'net/http'

def check_start_application(address, port)
  success_codes = [200, 301]
  attempts = 200
  uri = URI.parse("#{address}:#{port}")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

  attempts.times do |attempt|
    # it raises EOFError: end of file reached
    http.request_get(uri) do |response|
      if success_codes.include?(response.code.to_i)
        return true
      elsif attempt == attempts - 1
        return false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But, when I test this method separately from a context with irb, this code works pretty well for two cases:

```
check_start_application('http://example.com', '80')
check_start_application('http://localhost', any_port)
```

In an app's context this code works for only one case:

```
check_start_application('http://example.com', '80')
```

What I tried:

- using 'rest-client' instead of 'net/http'
- using 'net/https' with `http.use_ssl = false`
- remove `times` from the method
- call `sleep` before a request

Who faced a similar problem? I believe I'm not the only one.

Comment: On which port your code is failing? Is your app running on https ?

Comment: @rorra
Thx.
My app deploys on a random free port, and I use Docker for this. The range of ports is within an ephemeral port range.
The app isn't running on https.

Comment: @rorra I got what I want through %x(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent 127.0.0.1:#{any_port}). But it's not the right way to check response.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that on the deploy your app is running on SSL. It's hard to help debug without access to it, but try with:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
```